# Prevent FlexChild from growing

Tags: css, flexbox

Given the following code:

```css
.outer-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.left-container {
  height: 300px;
}

.right-container {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer-container'>
  <div class='left-container'>Lefto</div>
  <div class='right-container'>Righto</div>
</div>
```

The right container will grow to be 300px high, despite the `flex-grow` property being set to 0. How do I prevent this from happening? I.E., I want the right container to only be as tall as its content.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/MaxMillington2/pen/PxOwxo

Comment: you are mixing main and cross axis. The flex grow apply to the main axis (so will affect the widh) and not the cross axis (will not affect the height)

Comment: `flex-grow` has nothing to do with your problem. Check the duplicates for  explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `align-self: flex-start` on the `.right-container`

```css
.outer-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.left-container {
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.right-container {
  align-self: flex-start;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer-container'>
  <div class='left-container'>Lefto</div>
  <div class='right-container'>Righto</div>
</div>
```

Note: `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis` are for controlling how the space is filled along the *main axis*. In this case, the main axis is left-right because the `flex-direction` is set to `row` by default.

> The `align-items` property will align the items on the cross axis. The initial value for this property is `stretch` and this is why flex items stretch to the height of the tallest one by default.

[MDN - Concepts of Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

That is why you need to override either `align-items` on your `.outer-container` or `align-self` to the flex children.